# ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'lisans' in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to calculate the silhouette index of the output of k-prototypes algorithm to cluster mixed featured dataset. I am getting ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'lisans' as an error, even if my code works fine when I only execute k-prototypes algorithm. My input is an excel file, there is no space or indent in my cells. The error is below:

```
  File "C:\Users\...\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 433, in check_array
array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'lisans'
```

And here where the validation.py gives error :
[image]

Also, whenever I change the place of the columns in the excel file, the new column that is replaced with the old column's position that previously gave error also gives an error at the same place no matter what is the text written in the cells.

I also tried to create a new excel file and used that but I was unsuccessful again. Here is the code below:

```
#silhouette score index calculation
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from sklearn.metrics import silhouette_samples, silhouette_score
range_n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

for n_clusters in range_n_clusters:
# Create a subplot with 1 row and 2 columns
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.set_size_inches(18, 7)

# The 1st subplot is the silhouette plot
# The silhouette coefficient can range from -1, 1 but in this example all
# lie within [-0.1, 1]
ax1.set_xlim([-0.1, 1])
# The (n_clusters+1)*10 is for inserting blank space between silhouette
# plots of individual clusters, to demarcate them clearly.
ax1.set_ylim([0, len(X) + (n_clusters + 1) * 10])

# Initialize the clusterer with n_clusters value and a random generator
# seed of 10 for reproducibility.
clusterer = KPrototypes(n_clusters=n_clusters, init = 'Cao', verbose = 2)
cluster_labels = clusterer.fit_predict(X, categorical=[0, 8, 9])

# The silhouette_score gives the average value for all the samples.
# This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
# clusters
silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
      "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)

# Compute the silhouette scores for each sample
sample_silhouette_values = silhouette_samples(X, cluster_labels)

y_lower = 10
for i in range(n_clusters):
    # Aggregate the silhouette scores for samples belonging to
    # cluster i, and sort them
    ith_cluster_silhouette_values = \
        sample_silhouette_values[cluster_labels == i]

    ith_cluster_silhouette_values.sort()

    size_cluster_i = ith_cluster_silhouette_values.shape[0]
    y_upper = y_lower + size_cluster_i

    color = cm.spectral(float(i) / n_clusters)
    ax1.fill_betweenx(np.arange(y_lower, y_upper),
                      0, ith_cluster_silhouette_values,
                      facecolor=color, edgecolor=color, alpha=0.7)

    # Label the silhouette plots with their cluster numbers at the middle
    ax1.text(-0.05, y_lower + 0.5 * size_cluster_i, str(i))

    # Compute the new y_lower for next plot
    y_lower = y_upper + 10  # 10 for the 0 samples

ax1.set_title("The silhouette plot for the various clusters.")
ax1.set_xlabel("The silhouette coefficient values")
ax1.set_ylabel("Cluster label")

# The vertical line for average silhouette score of all the values
ax1.axvline(x=silhouette_avg, color="red", linestyle="--")

ax1.set_yticks([])  # Clear the yaxis labels / ticks
ax1.set_xticks([-0.1, 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])

# 2nd Plot showing the actual clusters formed
colors = cm.spectral(cluster_labels.astype(float) / n_clusters)
ax2.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], marker='.', s=30, lw=0, alpha=0.7,
            c=colors, edgecolor='k')

# Labeling the clusters
centers = clusterer.cluster_centers_
# Draw white circles at cluster centers
ax2.scatter(centers[:, 0], centers[:, 1], marker='o',
            c="white", alpha=1, s=200, edgecolor='k')

for i, c in enumerate(centers):
    ax2.scatter(c[0], c[1], marker='$%d$' % i, alpha=1,
                s=50, edgecolor='k')

ax2.set_title("The visualization of the clustered data.")
ax2.set_xlabel("Feature space for the 1st feature")
ax2.set_ylabel("Feature space for the 2nd feature")

plt.suptitle(("Silhouette analysis for KMeans clustering on sample data "
              "with n_clusters = %d" % n_clusters),
             fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')

plt.show()
```

This silhouette score code also works fine with other datasets without giving an error. Is there anyone who can fix it? (I had some problems while copying the code so normally indents are correct in sourcecode)

Comment: Is that the full Traceback? looks like some is missing... It shows the error coming from sklearn's validation.py file in the check_array function/method, however we don't know what called that in the code provided. At the very least provide the traceback up to the point where we could see the last point in you file that passed data into sklearn.

Comment: When I debug, at here the code goes to validation and gives error:

    > c:\users\...\part 4 - clustering\section 24 - k-means clustering\kprot_ben.py(69)<module>()
     67     # This gives a perspective into the density and separation of the formed
     68     # clusters
---> 69     silhouette_avg = silhouette_score(X, cluster_labels)
     70     print("For n_clusters =", n_clusters,
     71           "The average silhouette_score is :", silhouette_avg)


ipdb> ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'SECIM_YOK'

Answer (score 0):

In your `silhouette_score`  call, you compute all pairwise Euclidean distances.

That is not possible if you have a cell that contains the string value `"lisans"`.

You likely need to first compute a pairwise distance matrix, then use `metric="precomputed"`.

Comment: unfortunately using precomputed as a metric did not work either. Still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you precompute the distance matrix? Of course just setting the option is not enough. You also need to pass an appropriate distance matrix then, *not* the data array (that obviously still contains `"lisans"`.

Comment: My dataset is 632 rows and 12 colums. When I calculate the distance matrix, it asks for input y -> distance_matrix(x, y, p=2, threshold=1000000). Could you explain how I can fit my dataset ? Because x and y are matrix of m and n vectors in k dimensions ccording to the documentation, but I did not understand how I can provide the input.

Comment: You probably want y=x. But make sure to use the distance function you want... Or you'll get the same size again.